# Experimenting with objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas

I started learning JavaScript on Codecademy a few days ago, and took Lost Decade's [Simple Canvas Game](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/) as a base, and I was wondering: how could I add multiple enemies? I know that it's possible, but I've had great difficulty getting it to work.

[Here's my code *before* I broke everything.](http://pastebin.com/JikX9Xfh)

EDIT: I've added movement to the one monster, but not sure about creating another monster object and having my functions play nice with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you have a singleton object, `monster`, and all your function calls are directly manipulating the properties of that one object. `monster` is declared in the same scope (the global scope) as all of your functions so they can access it with no problems.

To create > 1 monster at the very least you'll need to rewrite all your functions to accept a `monster` object, then you can manipulate the properties of each one by passing THAT monster in as an argument e.g.

```
var changeMonsterDirections = function(theMonster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            theMonster.directions[i] = directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];
    }
    // If both directions are the same, null out one of them so that
    // the monster doesn't move twice as fast
    if (theMonster.directions[0] == theMonster.directions[1]) {
            theMonster.directions[1] = null;
    }
```

}

Then if you have

```
var monster1 = {
    speed: 200,
    directions: [null, null]
};
var monster2 = {
    speed: 200,
    directions: [null, null]
};
```

you can pass them around to your functions, like so

```
changeMonsterDirections(monster1);
changeMonsterDirections(monster2);
```

The above will work with your program as written but isn't object-oriented or good programming practice. A discussion of how to make your game work with proper OOP is beyond the scope of SO - try

http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

or similar, Google around for others. Good luck.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'll try this out in a bit and get back to you! Finals are tomorrow. D:

Comment: Also, make sure you always use === rather than == when checking for equality in JavaScript. It could save you headaches. Codeacademy is great but it really holds your hand and you don't have to think too much - I'd recommend CodeSchool for a deeper dive but you have to pay for it.